# Vector space obtained from translation of a affine space

Tags: linear-algebra

If $L$ is a affine subspace of $E_n$ and $b\in L$, then the set $T_{-b}(L)\subset E_n$, where $T_{-b}(x):=x-b, x\in L$, is a vector subspace of $E_n$.

I saw a demonstration that use a "trick" and prove first that $\alpha \,v \in L$, and next that $v_1+v_2 \in L$.

My question is about another demonstration wich consider that $z:=\alpha\, T_b(y_1)+\beta\, T_b(y_2)+(1-\alpha-\beta)b \in L$, because $T_b(y_1)$ and $T_b(y_2)$ belong to $L$ for $y_i\in T_{-b}(L)$.

I don't understand why $z \in L$. Can someone help?

Thanks

p.s.: $E_n$ is the usual euclidean vector space, $v_i\in E_n$ and $\alpha,\beta$ are scalars

Comment: Because $b\in L$ and because $T_b(y_1)$ and $T_b(y_2)$ belong to $L$, also $z$ belongs to $L$.

Comment: But is not be $\alpha T_b(y_1) + \beta T_b (y_2)  + (2 - \alpha - \beta) b \in L$? Apparently, expanding the terms of $z$, should be appear a $2$ for satisfie the definition of affine subspace.